# A function to generate very unique combination of letters and numbers in dart

Tags: flutter, dart

I am developing an app with dart and flutter and I am trying to create a unique ID for each user signing in, I have 3 categories of users.

I want to generate a unique number for each user registering with a prefix of letters referencing the user category.

E.g.
Category 1 **PH175589**
Category 2 **MS897841**
Category 3 **DR632514**

Any user in category1 starts with *PH*.

Any user in category2 starts with *MS*.

Any user in category3 starts with *DR*.

I have read about the random function in `dart:math`, where it generates random numbers but they are not always unique. How can I achieve the above example and ensure that it will always give me a unique number for each user?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```dart
import 'dart:math'; // needed to generate random number

List<String> ids = []; // a list of all the ids to keep track of what is used up;

void main() {
  String id = generateVeryUniqueID(2); // generates id for categories 1-3
  ids.add(id); // adds id to list so that it is not generated later
  print(id);
}

String generateVeryUniqueID(int category) {
  
  String cat = "";
  
  switch(category) {
    case 1: cat="PH"; break;
    case 2: cat="MS"; break;
    case 3: cat="DR"; break;
  }
  
  bool unique = false;
  var rng = new Random();
  
  String numbers = "";
  while(!unique) {
    numbers = "";
    for(var i = 0; i<6; i++) {
      numbers+=rng.nextInt(9).toString();
    }
    if(!ids.contains(cat+numbers)) {
      unique = true;
    }
  }
  return cat+numbers;
}
```

Comment: I would use a Map, not a List.  No point doing a linear search on a list... might as well use the power of the hash!

Comment: Also, don't append to a `String` but use a `StringBuffer`. And don't make a new instance of `Random` for each call of `generateVeryUniqueID` but keep an instance as a global or class static variable.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this

```dart
import 'package:id_gen/id_gen.dart';

const gen = UuidV4Gen();
final userA = 'PH-${gen.get().hash()}';
final userB = 'MS-${gen.get().hash()}';
```

from the lightweight and well-tested Dart package https://pub.dev/packages/id_gen

Or if the risk of collisions is unacceptable:

```dart
final userA = 'PH-${gen.get()}';
final userB = 'MS-${gen.get()}';
```